# EXC_BREAKPOINT in RKManagedObjectRequestOperation NSManagedObjectContext::save

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode8, restkit, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm getting this inconsistent, hard to reproduce crash in RestKit. The crash occurs on `NSManagedObjectContext::save()`, inside `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation::saveContextToPersistentStore:failedContext:error` ([here's the exact line of code](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/v0.27.0/Code/Network/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m#L800)).

This crash happened to over a dozen different users in our production environment but I've personally been unable to reproduce it. I have no clue as to what might be causing this crash. My only clue is `_forceRegisterLostFault` which may suggest faulted/deleted objects are involved.

Background: `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation::saveContextToPersistentStore:failedContext:error` is invoked every time RestKit mapping is completed following a network request.

Has anyone encountered this particular EXC_BREAKPOINT in CoreData before? 
Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Stack trace:

```
Crashed: NSManagedObjectContext 0x1741cf5a0
0  CoreData                       0x18add7c7c -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _forceRegisterLostFault:] + 160
1  CoreData                       0x18ad5c8b0 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _validateObjects:forOperation:error:exhaustive:forSave:] + 2884
2  CoreData                       0x18ad5bcf8 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _validateChangesForSave:] + 364
3  CoreData                       0x18ad5b94c -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _prepareForPushChanges:] + 196
4  CoreData                       0x18ad51ec4 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 544
5  RestKit                        0x1013214b8 __84-[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation saveContextToPersistentStore:failedContext:error:]_block_invoke (RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:800)
6  CoreData                       0x18add5b70 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 152
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1878e91c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1878f6860 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 84
9  CoreData                       0x18add5a80 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 308
10 RestKit                        0x1013212b8 -[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation saveContextToPersistentStore:failedContext:error:] (RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:808)
11 RestKit                        0x1013216d0 -[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation saveContext:error:] (RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:831)
12 RestKit                        0x101321f54 -[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation saveContext:] (RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:874)
13 RestKit                        0x10131f654 __79-[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation performMappingOnResponseWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke.350 (RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:660)
14 RestKit                        0x1013534a0 -[RKResponseMapperOperation willFinish] (RKResponseMapperOperation.m:323)
15 RestKit                        0x101353ac4 -[RKResponseMapperOperation main] (RKResponseMapperOperation.m:411)
16 Foundation                     0x1894578c4 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 620
17 Foundation                     0x189524b00 __NSOQSchedule_f + 228
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x1878e91c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x1878f7444 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 928
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x1878ec9a8 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 652
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x1878f938c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x1878f90ec _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
23 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x187af22b8 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x187af1da4 start_wqthread + 4
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different causes I've seen for this error.

- Accessing Managed Objects and/or Contexts on the wrong thread. Use [Core Data Concurrency Debugging](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/) to validate that you're always using the right thread, with the `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` argument.
- Corrupted Sqlite file - does your app include an out-of-box Core Data store? Make sure all the metadata in it is correct.
- [Overriding the default accessors](https://twitter.com/drewmccormack/status/559295627931430912) in your Core Data Managed Objects. Be careful if you have objects with primitive (int or float instead of NSNumber) properties.

Comment: Enabling `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` reveals several crashes inside RestKit related to CoreData concurrency. I've raised one [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/2502). Not sure if that has to do anything with the crash I'm experiencing though. These concurrency issues seem to be part of RestKit by design.

Comment: Does it make sense to encapsulate all fetching code in dispatch.main blocks?